# How to set the same legend (Label) to different scatter points in my plot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, legend

Need some guidance handling legends with matplotlib/pylab.

```
for xe, ye in zip(dist, liston):
    plt.scatter([xe] * len(ye), ye, s = 200, color = 'darkseagreen')
```

where:

```
dist = [2.0, 4.0, 6.0, 8.0, 10.0, 12.0, 14.0, 16.0, 18.0, 20.0]
liston = [[-46.6, -46.7, -53.0], [-52.4, -50.7, -51.0], [-54.2, -54.0, -52.8], [-53.3, -51.4, -54.2], [-56.8, -54.4, -52.4], [-55.5, -54.9, -55.7], [-59.1, -59.4, -57.0], [-58.4, -54.8, -58.8], [-56.7, -55.5, -62.3], [-56.2, -57.5, -59.1]]
```

My plot now has the points by distance (liston x dist), the errorbar and the mean of measures per distance (x axis). I have a legend with the Error and Mean up and running, but I'm failing to do so with the scatter points.

Since I'm running the scatter inside a looping, if I try to label there I will get 10 identical legends, which is not what I want.(Need to treat my 10 scatter plots as if it were one)

Any insights will be helpfull!

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would get rid of the loop and plot a single scatter.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

dist = [2.0, 4.0, 6.0, 8.0, 10.0, 12.0, 14.0, 16.0, 18.0, 20.0]
liston = [[-46.6, -46.7, -53.0], [-52.4, -50.7, -51.0], [-54.2, -54.0, -52.8], 
          [-53.3, -51.4, -54.2], [-56.8, -54.4, -52.4], [-55.5, -54.9, -55.7], 
          [-59.1, -59.4, -57.0], [-58.4, -54.8, -58.8], [-56.7, -55.5, -62.3], 
          [-56.2, -57.5, -59.1]]

y = np.array(liston).T
x = np.tile(dist, len(y))

plt.scatter(x, y, s = 200, color = 'darkseagreen', label="MyLabel")
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for that, '...'Ernest (?)! That does exactly what I wanted in a way I coudn't have imagined (: Best regards